# Parse List in nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension, python-jsonschema

```
data = {
    "persons": {"1": {"name": "siddu"}, "2": {"name": "manju"}},
    "cars": {
        "model1": {
            "make": 1990,
            "company_details": {
                "name": "Ford Corporation",
                "country": "US",
                "some_list": [1, 2, 1],
            },
        },
        "model2": {
            "make": 1990,
            "company_details": {
                "name": "Ford Corporation",
                "country": "US",
                "some_list": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
            },
        },
    },
}
```

This is my python object, How can I identify the Key's-Value is a list. example here, after traversing through 'print(data["cars"]["model1"]["company_details"]["some_list"])'I get the list, since it is small dictionary it was easy, but how can I identify the same if I encounter list as a value for some other key in future.

Example:

```
data = {
    "persons": {"1": {"name": "siddu"}, "2": {"name": "manju"}},
    "cars": {
        "model1": {
            "make": 1990,
            "company_details": {
                "name": "Ford Corporation",
                "country": "US",
                "some_list": [1, 2, 1],
            },
        },
        "model2": {
            "make": 1990,
            "company_details": {
                "name": "Ford Corporation",
                "country": ["US", "UK", "IND"],
                "some_list": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Can anyone please suggest/guide me to understand how to identify the key's value is a list.
The final goal is to remove the duplicates in the list if any exists?
Thank you very much:)

Comment: Be it JSON or Dictionary, your data should follow a specific schema for such things to work.. is that the case with yours or is it like a random data structure?

Comment: It is a JSON file, I converted it to dict.

Comment: Look up `isinstance()` In the Python documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a recursive function that goes to any depth and make the items of the list unique like below:

```
In [8]: def removeDuplicatesFromList(di):
   ...:     for key, val in di.items():
   ...:         if isinstance(val, dict):
   ...:             removeDuplicatesFromList(val)
   ...:         elif isinstance(val, list):
   ...:             di[key] =list(set(val))
   ...:         else:
   ...:             continue
   ...:
   ...:
In [9]: removeDuplicatesFromList(data)

In [10]: data
Out[10]:
{'persons': {'1': {'name': 'siddu'}, '2': {'name': 'manju'}},
 'cars': {'model1': {'make': 1990,
   'company_details': {'name': 'Ford Corporation',
    'country': 'US',
    'some_list': [1, 2]}},
  'model2': {'make': 1990,
   'company_details': {'name': 'Ford Corporation',
    'country': 'US',
    'some_list': [1, 2]}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Arun Kaliraja Baskaran

Comment: Do mark the answer correct if it solves your problem:)